# Jquery mobile navbar not active after session log in (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-mobile

1) This is my Login page:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign In') %>
<div data-role="page" data-url="/signin/">
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
<div>
    <%= f.text_field :username_or_email, placeholder: "username or email", autofocus: true %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "password" %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.submit "Sign In", rel: "external" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

2) This is my Home page after login:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-url="/users/<%= @user.id %>/" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
        <h4>Home</h4>
        <%= link_to 'New', new_pin_path, rel: "external" %>
    </div>
    <% if !@user.pins.any? %>
        <h3>Welcome to Pins!... Enter your first pin.</h3>
    <% end %>
    <%= render @user.pins %>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu">    
    <div class="ui-grid-a center">
        <div class="ui-block-a menublock">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b menublock">
            <%= link_to 'Friends Pins', pins_path %>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-a menublock">
            <%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_path(current_user) %>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b menublock">
            <%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So basically, after I log in and try clicking on `<a href="#menu">Menu</a>` I get no response (unless I refresh the page).**

3) This is how my session login works:
I was going to paste it but it's super long, I basically used the same thing that is going on here:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top

4) Trailing slashes ([this is a requirement by jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)): I thought my problem may be because I did not have trailing slashes set on all the urls, so I added this to my application.rb: `config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }` And although it fixed a lot of the navigation between pages, it does not fix the issue after my session log in.

5) Also note that when I refresh the home page after login, the navbar *does* work correctly.

Comment: Are you using any javascript on that link?

Comment: Also, try adding `data-role="button"` to a_tag and see if changes anything.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a "data-rel" tag. Try the following:

```
<a href="#menu" data-rel="dialog">Menu</a>
```